# Looking for a subclass of deterministic context-free languages, other than the subclass of regular languages

Tags: formal-languages, context-free, reference-request, formal-grammars

Let $X=\{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ be a finite set of alphabet and $X^\ast$ denote the set of all words (including empty word) over $X$. Clearly, $X^\ast$ is a regular language.

Is there a subclass, say $C$, of deterministic context-free (DCF) languages over $X$ such that if $L \in C$, then $ X^{\ast}LX^{\ast} \in C$ and the generating function of $L$ is a non-rational (algebraic) function?

How can one describe a DCF grammar of $ X^{\ast}LX^{\ast}$, for  $L\in C$?

Comment: In other words, you are looking for a DCFL language $L$ such that $X^*LX^*$ is also DCFL. If you find such a language, then $C = \{L,X^*LX^*\}$ is a solution. Conversely, if you take any $L \in C$, then $X^*LX^* \in C$ and so both $L$ and $X^*LX^*$ are DCFL.